# Trigger with ID not firing correctly

Tags: google-tag-manager

I created a trigger to fire when CSS selector contains `#buy-btn` as the ID of a button on my page.
Once I tested, I noticed that the tag with the trigger did not fire properly, as can be seen below:

[image: error]

Here is the trigger setting:

[image: trigger setting]

And this is the code snippet of the button itself:

```html
<button data-v-907e9fb6="" type="button" class="shop-button buy-btn v-btn v-btn--has-bg v-btn--rounded theme--light v-size--default" id="buy-btn" style="width: 80%;"><span class="v-btn__content">구매하기 </span></button>
```

Is there anything I am missing here? Would someone kindly take a look?

Answer (score 0):

GTM registers a click on the span that is nested inside the button. The id is on the button itself. So you need to change your selector to target the span instead (some people write this for simplicity with a wildcard to match all nested elements).

Comment: Hi Eike, thanks for the answer.